# Completely disable ADAM in 2SXC

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

is there any way to completely disable ADAM in 2sxc?

or at least hide everything related to it?
I don't want the users to use it or even to ask me what is it , I completely prefer to use the old traditional way of managing files.

Thanks

[image: ADAM]

Comment: did you check the settings of a hyperlink field? I think you can disable it there...

Comment: @iJungleBoy did you mean this option? https://screenpresso.com/=52smb , if yes, then yes I've disabled it from the beginning, it only hides the ADAM button

Comment: Curious if you've ever figured out how to disable ADAM at all? I disabled everything on the hyperlink field setting and it still shows ADAM.  Choosing Image Manager also still uploads using ADAM when files are dragged and dropped.

Comment: @walroar unfortunately I couldn't, just like you I've tried many things but that annoying thing still appears and makes arranging and splitting files into the correct folders more susceptible to errors by the site content manager (because ADAM does not respect the property 'Paths' , like the old file pickers (not ADAM), which is the most annoying thing).

Comment: The good news is that I remember I have read somewhere on their blog that Daniel (iJungleBoy) is working on a feature to enable/disable ADAM and it will be available in the near future (God bless him), but I could not find the link at present.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to remove all Adam field hints:

```
var dropzone = document.getElementsByClassName('dropzone');
for (i = 0; i < dropzone.length; i++) { 
  var input = dropzone[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
  input[0].removeAttribute("uib-tooltip");
  var hint = dropzone[i].getElementsByTagName('adam-hint');
  hint[0].remove();
}
```

Note the remove() function is DOM level 4 which may not be supported everywhere (https://catalin.red/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/). You can do that with removeChild() also but you'll need to do a little more work to get the direct parent of the adam-hint.

Comment: unfortunately this only removed 'adam-hint' , but 'uib-tooltip' is still there and will appear when hovering the input... I hate ADAM as much as I like the other features (a lot).